# Allow "-" and "." in preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

```
$username = preg_replace("/[^\p{L}|\p{N}]/u", "", html_entity_decode($username));
```

This allows "letters" and "numbers" in the `$username`, removing everything else.

But how can I also **allow** `"."` dot symbols in the mix? also `"-"` would be nice.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I've never seen the `\p{L}` syntax.  Anyone have the docs for this?

Comment: @RocketHazmat me neither. But here, I found it: http://www.php.net/manual/de/regexp.reference.unicode.php

Comment: Found it! http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html  It's apparently for unicode matches.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add those into your character class:

```
$var = 'Василий. Теркин-';
$username = preg_replace('/[^\p{L}\p{N}.-]/u', "", $var);
var_dump($username); // Василий.Теркин-
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/80728). I have removed `|`, as it obviously is covered by the character class already (and obviously shouldn't be used in a character class as an alternation - after all, class IS an alternation). )

Comment: +1 for the first answer to not try to force a `[a-z]`

Comment: don't escaped characters always have to come at the beginning of a character group? I seem to remember something like that.

Comment: @Tim No. Even `-` - which does have a special meaning within a character class - might be thrown either at the beginning or at the end. The only point here is to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: Ok, thanks for clearing that up. For regexes, I often have to read the PCRE man pages. I can never remember the details.

Answer (score 3):

`.` has no meaning in a character class, so doesn't need escaping. `-` has no meaning either IF it is the first or last character.

```
$username = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9.-]/u","",html_entity_decode($username));
```

Comment: I dont want to user (a-z) since some names might be foreign

Comment: á ,for example, also counts as a letter I believe

Comment: as (a-z) @Tim? What about "ñ" etc

Comment: @James yeah, I was writing to the answerer not to you. This regex isn't what you want.

Answer (score -1):

Escape them with a `\`

I don't get the rest of your regex honestly but that's how you use special characters.

The regex I would use is: `[a-z0-9\-\.]` (add the case insensitive flag).

Comment: A `.` doesn't need to be escaped in a character group. Also the `-` can be put as the first character to avoid escaping: e.g. `[-.blah]`

Comment: So... `/[^\p{L}|\p{N}|\-|\.}]/u`  like this?

Comment: The OPs regex matches unicode character properties. I think that includes more than just a-z, so yours isn't equivalent.

Comment: @James `|` is *just a normal character* inside a character group (`[]`).

Comment: @James `|` is only used in parentheses. In brackets, it literally means `|`.